# Hat Name is not in English

Tags: support, winter-bash, languages, winter-bash-2020

My default language in Stack Overflow is English and all other hat names are in English but this one is not:

[image: Hat Image]

I am suspecting it is a language error because of the dots above the "u" and "e" letters. Which language is this and what is the meaning of it?

Comment: Some loan words in English: [voilà](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voil%C3%A0#Interjection) and [coup d'état](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coup_d%27%C3%A9tat#Noun).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's French, and it's a [Christmas cake](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/17345/buche-de-noel/). Not everybody spells it with accents though:

> Buche de Noel is the French name for a Christmas cake shaped like a log. This one is a heavenly flourless chocolate cake rolled with chocolate whipped cream. Traditionally, Buche de Noel is decorated with confectioners' sugar to resemble snow on a Yule log.

Omitting accents seems quite common, even [a reputable dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noel) writes 'noel' without.

Comment: Ooooh, I have got a Cake for Christmas from Stackoverflow. they can just rename it to English right?

Comment: However, I find it more pretty with accents, which sometimes differentiates different words in cases like "sale" (dirty) and "salé" (salted) in French.

Comment: @Vignesh it is a specific type of cake that has no name in English. For example, if it were "Baklava", it would also not be possible to translate it. The good news is that you learned something today, which is also a benefit of some of the hats.

Comment: @wimi Thanaks a lot